# 特定のSocketをcloseしたい

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

NodeJS(SocketIO)でチャットのアプリケーションを作成している者です。

特定のユーザに送信するのに下記の方法を用いています。

```
io.to(socket.id).json.emit('message', message);
```

特定のユーザのsocketをソケットIDを用いて、閉じるにはどうしたらいいですか。

Answer (score 1):

```
io.sockets.connected[socket.id].disconnect();
```

`Socket#id`からSocketを参照するには`Namespace#connected`を使うようです。
なのでNamespaceを使わない場合は上記のようにデフォルトのNamespace`/`へのエイリアスである`Server#sockets`を使います。
[公式のサーバーサイドAPIのドキュメント](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/)